# How can I add Remove method to ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, telerik

I have a raddataform control which uses ObservableCollection as input source and auto generates fields.I have implemented Insert and Edit Logic in the person class itself which implements IEditableObject and INotifyPropertyChanged through BeginEdit and EndEdit methods. but public void Delete() method wont work there.also I learned that ObservableCollection has CollectionChanged event which has NotifyChangedCollectionAction.Remove .So how can I implement delete(remove) logic on ObservableCollection so that it can delete corresponding field using linq?
Here's code :

```
 public class EmployeeDataContext
{
    private ICollectionView employees = null;
    public ICollectionView Employees
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.employees == null)
            {
                ObservableCollection<Person> newEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
                DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

                var query = from c in db.EPersons
                            select c;
                foreach (var q in query)
                {
                    newEmployees.Add(new Person((DateTime)q.EStartingDate, q.EFirstName,q.ELastName, (Person.OccupationPositions) q.EOccupation,q.EPhoneNumber, (int)q.ESalary));
                }                
                //newEmployees.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
                //    {
                //        if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove) 
                //    }
            return this.employees;

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, `EmployeeDataContext.Employees:get` will *always* `return null;`

Comment: @Binkan Salaryman yes,while initialization in mainwindow constructor there iis DataContext = new EmployeeDataContext() ; and EmployeeDataContext.Employees:get will return null then it will get collection through querying the database( linq)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the DataConext object from your event handler's evenargs on your codebehind for BeginEdit and EndEdit.

Then call your viewmodel's Delete method referencing the DataContext retieved.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure that I fully understand your question, but if you're asking how you can add a custom `Remove` method to the `ObservableCollection<T>` class, then you can use [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). Perhaps something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool Remove<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        var someObject;
        // custom logic here
        return collection.Remove(someObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this works, as it actually **hides** the old method! The last line will probably lead to a **recursion** and an attempt to call the extension method will call the *actual* `Remove` method of `ObservableCollection<T>`. I suggest to properly name it to something like  `RemoveWithLogicX`.

Comment: Look again and notice the `'<T>'` in `Remove<T>` this time. This is a generic method, unlike the default one from the `ObservableCollection<T>` class.

Comment: Even if it works - it tends to confuse, as the generic variant does a `custom logic` and the non-generic does not. Without generic parameters one could expect the compiler to infer the type. Don't be angry at me, but I'm giving you a downvote for the poor design.

Comment: the main problem is that there is no event handler for raddataform like btn_Click(), It implicitly depends on list or collection you are  using .ex ObservableCollection has add ,remove functionalities .heres full code: [link]http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DataForm/FirstLook

Comment: Then create a class that extends the `ObservableCollection<T>` class and override the `Remove` method to put your custom logic in there instead.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, if you really get confused by method overloads, you'll have a problem being a developer.

Comment: It is bad design, it has nothing to do with skills. Please stay polite.

Comment: What exactly is a bad design? Using extension methods? Overriding methods? Neither of those are bad designs.

Comment: 1. Extension methods need import statements to work. 2. Generic type parameters can be inferred by the compiler 3. `Remove` does not keep the one *with* and *without* distinct in spite of their important difference in logic 4. Ask JonSkeet, and he will agree with me 5. Don't start an unrelated discussion here

Comment: Wow! Each to their own.

Comment: Having point 1 and 2, a call to `Remove` and `Remove<T>` can depend on having imported the Extension class. Don't tell me this is intended.